# Are protocols inheritable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I saw this in some header file in the framework directory:

```
@interface NSCharacterSet : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSCoding>

@end

@interface NSMutableCharacterSet : NSCharacterSet <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying>

@end
```

I thought protocols were inheritable.If I am right about that,There is no need to type `<NSCopying, NSMutableCopying>` again after "`NSMutableCharacterSet : NSCharacterSet`".And NSMutableCharacterSet also conforms to NSCoding protocol, right?

Than why is Apple typing that again?Am I making mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Subclasses will adopt the same protocols as well.

The reason Apple typing that again is because NSMutableCharacterSet has overridden `-copyWithZone:` and `-mutableCopyWithZone:`.